# Can't save object in production environment only with Ruby 1.9.3 (but it worked with 1.8.7)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a problem that when I try to save an object in the DB, in the development environment it works OK but in the production environment it doesn't save anything.

This problem appears only with Ruby 1.9.3; with 1.8.7, it works ok in both environments. I'm using Rails 3.0.10 and this code; it's part of rake script.

```
if @preproduct.save
   puts "Preproduct added successfully"
else   
   puts "Preproduct error, was not added"
end
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: try it with `@preproduct.save!` and show us errors.

Comment: Is this a gem? If so, is the gem compatible with Ruby 1.9?

Comment: i try guys ... the error appear in the @object.save block, the problem it's that nothings happend on production.log ! it's so stranger

Comment: there's a big problem ... nothing show the log on production enviorment only! (Only using ruby 1.9.3 with 1.8.7 works all fine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix this using this code on rake script and then fix the attributes when create the object.

```
require 'logger'
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
```